# Diff bug in suggested edits?

Tags: support, status-completed, suggested-edits, diff

The rendered output diff seems to be having problems for this suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4614

As far as I can tell from looking at the Markdown diff, the suggested edit is valid and good, but the rendered output diff makes it look like the suggested edit completely mangles the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me now (as far as possible anyway). We have recently made great improvements to the HTML diff engine, and this is an example where that's clearly visible.

Answer (score 5):

This is correct, sometimes you can't do a sane diff on the cooked version.

Just use the icons in the left column to switch from cooked (html) to raw (markdown) diffs.

Comment: I'd love it if SO remembered that I prefer the raw diff, even if just through a cookie.  I work with a lot of questions that have angle braces and have on at least one occasion rejected an edit because I thought they were [adding generics into a question](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/18385), when really they were just increasing the indent :-).  The cooked diff is really cool, but I find myself almost always going back to the raw diff manually (at least now that I've learned my lesson).